# In frontend PUT request returning Internal Server 500 error | Django Vue

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

I am trying to perform a `PUT` request in Vue view from DRF API backend. Though `POST` and `GET` requests are working properly in Vue(frontend) but for `PUT` request it's returning `INTERNAL SERVER ERROR 500`

Here is what I have done.

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'articles'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ]
}

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:8080"
]
```

**views.py**

```
class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
```

**view.vue**

```
updateArticle(article) {
            axios
                .put('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/' + article.id,
                    this.article
                )
                .then(response => {
                    this.fetchArticle();
                    this.editArticle = null;
                    return response;
                })
                .catch(error => console.log(error))
        }
```

**urls.py**

```
from .views import ArticleViewSet
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'', ArticleViewSet, basename='articles')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Comment: Normally if you get a 500, the stacktrace will be posted in the console where your django server is running, could you post that? Also, the code of your `ArticleViewSet` would be very helpful.

Comment: @GlennDJ, it's running in localhost `127.0.0.1:8000`. `ArticleViewSet` just added.

Comment: I meant the console window where you run your server code. However, I just noticed that you put `this.article` in your js code, while you are fetching the `id` from `article`. I assume one of those 2 is incorrect?

Comment: @GlennDJ console window server is `localhost:8080`. And it shows `PUT http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/3 500 (Internal Server Error)`. full code of Article.vue [link](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/3WWYpvZMVZ/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You called this URL via PUT, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining PUT data.

Just add `'/'` at the end of the URL

In your **view.vue**

```
updateArticle(article) {
            axios
                .put('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/' + article.id + '/',
                    this.article
                )
                .then(response => {
                    this.fetchArticle();
                    this.editArticle = null;
                    return response;
                })
                .catch(error => console.log(error))
        }
```